# Qt theme and colors disturbed when built using cmake

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, qtgui, qtwidgets

I have a Qt application (Qt5) on linux which runs (and looks) perfectly fine. I have developed this using Qt Creator and so it gets built with the help of qmake by default.

But when I use cmake to build this project, the colors of all the widgets are disturbed (shown as below). Am I missing something anything in my CMakeLists file?

Here is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)

set (PROJECT_NAME QtTrialBuild)
project (${PROJECT_NAME})

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)


set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES})
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")

set ( SOURCES
main.cpp
imageviewer.cpp
CRubberBand.cpp
CImageSelector.cpp
CSelectablePicture.cpp
CScale.cpp
)

set ( MOC_HEADERS
imageviewer.h
CRubberBand.h
CImageSelector.h
CSelectablePicture.h
CScale.h
)

set ( UIS
 imageviewer.ui
)

qt5_wrap_ui( UI_HEADERS ${UIS} )
qt5_wrap_cpp( MOC_SRCS ${MOC_HEADERS} )

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${MOC_SRCS} ${UI_HEADERS})

target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets)
```

When built with Qt Creator this is how the window looks (and that's how wanted it to be too)

[image]

But with Cmake

this is how it looked when built with cmake

[image]

The colors of the buttons, borders and pop-up windows are changed. Did I miss any parameters or did I forget to add something in the cmakelists?

Answer (score 1):

`QT5_ADD_RESOURCES` seems to be missing:

```
set(YourProject_RC
    YourProject.qrc
    YourProject2.qrc
)

QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(YourProject_RC_SRCS ${YourProject_RC})

add_executable(YourProject.UI
    ...
    ${YourProject_RC_SRCS}
    ...
)
```

Comment: I don't have any .qrc files in my project. I am pretty new to Qt, so not sure if I need one. But I am not using any external resources